How to change date format if I use a MUI TextField with type of date?
I am using MUI TextField component with the type of Date to create a calendar. The default calendar date format is MM/DD/YYYY althouth I want it to be DD/MM/YYYY. Is there any possibility to change the date format of MUI TextField component.
Ex:
MUI Text field type="Date"
I was trying to fix this by going through MUI TextField API props and many google resources. But currently find no way to achieve this.

There are many answers on this question, but without a work-around, currently there is no format attribute.

Thanks a lot for your references, I get a lot from this question

You can use this example from Mui. From Mui X you can use Datepickeras
<DatePicker
  label="Date Picker"
  format="YYYY/MM/DD"
  defaultValue={dayjs('2022-04-17')}
/>


Hi @discovrer, Thank you so much for your comment. Previously I used MUI Datepicker and Date range picker. But the problem is those components does not allow us to type leading 0s. For example when type date as 05, the date field does not update when type 0. After write 5 it update as 05. That is why I decided to avoid datepicker and daterange picker.
